# Object always appears in front of the other

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

I'm having a problem with Blender where one object (bottom half) always appears in front of the other (top half). This doesn't occur when it is rendered.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5nIs.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have x-ray enabled for that object

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't know that existed haha

Answer (score 5):

For 2.8 plus the option is called *In Front* and can be found in the *Properties Window > Object > Viewport Display > In Front*

[image]