# display a grease pencil object ontop of a 3d model(despite location)

Tags: grease-pencil

I want the entirety of the grease pencil object to be displayed in front of the model

[image]

Is this possible to do **without needing to move the grease pencil object?**

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56703/object-always-appears-in-front-of-the-other/170363#170363

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to make the GP object always be in front of everything, then there is a setting for it. Check out this tutorial video to find out where (because I can't specifically remember where....):

https://youtu.be/1HRYC4Q1ajI

it's somewhere near the end, like past halfway. it had to do with depth order... may have moved from 2.8 to 2.82.

Hope that helps...